# Distinguishing between homophones in everyday speech

Tags: colloquial-language, spoken-language, homophonic-kanji

While trying to figure out the polite imperative form of 呼ぶ I figured the correct conjugation to be 呼んで下さい。I found instead that, colloquially, the imperative is 呼び出して下さい。 Am I correct in assuming that this is to distinguish between, 読んで and 呼んで in everyday speech?

Comment: I saw the title and thought you were asking about those _kango_ compounds. As in your case, 呼んで is よんで{LHH} and 読んで is よんで{HLL} so there's no chance we could mix them up.

Comment: Not to familiar with japanese enunciation just yet. I assume that the first case emphasizes よ while the second emphasizes んで？　As for the OP, then 呼んで下さい　is correct?

Comment: See [this post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11194/7810) about notation. Japanese has [pitch accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pitch_accent) that high or low is meaningful. 呼んで itself doesn't have accent core, so さ should be the accent peak in 呼んで下さい.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As 読んで and 呼んで have different accents in both standard Japanese and Kansai dialect.

呼ぶ and 呼び出す are...

- 呼ぶ: call someone.
- 呼び出す: call someone and ask him to come somewhere.

They are similar, sometimes same.