# What is the difference in pronunciation between [桃]{もも} and [腿]{もも}?

Tags: learning, pitch-accent

I am currently studying 日本語 and I am trying to understand the pronunciation difference between **桃** (peach) and **腿** (thigh). Both can be written as **もも** in kana and sound practically the same to me when my tutor pronounces them to me, but she tells me that there is a difference in terms of the pronunciation, though I can't figure out what it is and thus how to say them properly.

So what is the difference in pronunciation? Is it stress? Accent? And how do I pronounce them so that a 日本人 can tell which one of them it is that I mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41190/5010

Comment: Maybe these can be useful? https://forvo.com/word/桃/#ja and https://forvo.com/word/腿/#ja

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference is in the pitch accent.

桃 (peach)：「もも{LH}」 (Low-High)

腿 (thigh)：「もも{HL}」 (High-Low)

That is a ***huge*** difference to us native speakers because it changes the meanings of the words ***completely***.

If there is a musical instrument around you, try doing the following.

Hit 'do-mi' as you say 「桃」 and hit 'mi-do' as you try to say 「腿」.

Other examples from simple everyday words:

**Low-High**　「〇〇{LH}」: 「飴{あめ}」= hard candy,「橋{はし}」= bridge,「居間{いま}」= living room

**High-Low** 「〇〇{HL}」:「雨{あめ}」= rain,「箸{はし}」= chopsticks,「今{いま}」= now

(Finally, even at the risk of confusing some, I might mention for the advanced learners that the (feminine) given name 「桃/もも/モモ」 is pronounced the ***same*** way as 「腿」 --- 「もも{HL}」, that is.  This is an exception but it is a fact, so I had to say it.

Same thing with 「雪{ゆき}」. To mean "snow", it is pronounced 「ゆき{LH}」, but for a personal name, it is 「ゆき{HL}」.)

Note: All pronunciations above are naturally based on Standard Japanese.

Comment: There's also the distinction between low-high + gradually falling, and low-high + immediate downstep: 端が is はしが{LHH} with pitch pattern 0 (no downstep), whereas 橋が is はしが{LHL} with pitch pattern 2 (downstep after second mora).  I'm curious -- when pronounced in isolation (without particles), is there any perceivable difference between patterns 0 and 2?

Comment: @l'électeur You bring up an interesting point about pitch-accent and names. This is an area I find especially difficult because there are no authoritative resources I can find to help study this. For standard items of vocabulary, a pitch-accent dictionary can tell you all you need to know, making it easy to incorporate that information into your studies. But for names, there is no such equivalent. I am currently in the process of learning around 3000 first names/last names, but the lack of pitch-accent information is disheartening.