# Translation of "to buy a cat" vs "to own a cat"

Tags: homonyms

This question is to confirm that the two verbs (to buy and to have) are homophones.

> わたしはねこをかっています。

Could the above sentence be translated to "I have a cat" as well as "I am buying a cat"? Are there other ways to phrase the above sentence that are more specific to "buying" vs "having"?

Comment: Be aware that [飼]{か}う isn't 'have' in general, it's specifically 'have as a pet; take care of'.

Comment: @Sjiveru Ah okay, then would it also be used to refer to children? As in "わたしわむすこさんをかっています" (I have/take care of a son).

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53487/what-is-the-difference-in-pronunciation-between-%e6%a1%83%e3%82%82%e3%82%82-and-%e8%85%bf%e3%82%82%e3%82%82/53492#53492

Comment: @funseiki No.  You can only 飼う animals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are homophones, and this is why kanji is important.

- [買]{か}う　→　to buy
- [飼]{か}う　→　to keep/raise

I guess it *could* technically be used to say "I'm buying a cat", but no one would ever think that if they heard you say it.  If you really wanted to convey the fact that the action you're currently doing is buying a cat, you'd be better off using [購入]{こう・にゅう}している or 買いつつある.

> - 今は猫を購入しているところです。
>     OR
> - 今は猫を買いつつあります。

Even then, the latter is kind of suspect and could be ambiguous.

Comment: 買う is かう{LH} and かっている{LHHHH} while 飼う is かう{HL} and かっている{HLLLL}, so I'm not sure they can be called homophones.

Comment: @snailplane - what do the red lines signify?

Comment: @funseiki Pitch accent... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pitch_accent#Binary_pitch